# Find All Empty and Null fields in a database. How to output just the Column Name?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I got a script working that will look for empty spaces and NULL values in an entire database. Well technically speaking, in an schema from a database.

I modified the script from the following link: [Search every table and field in a SQL Server Database Updated](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated)

Problem is that the Final 2 columns I get as my output are  2 columns with the following example as the fields inside:

COLUMN 1: TableName

```
 [SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME]
 [SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME2]
 [SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME2]
 [SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME3]
 [SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME4]
 ...and so on
```

COLUMN 2: ColumnName

```
 [SHCEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME1]
 [SHCEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME2].[COLUMN_NAME1]
 [SHCEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME2].[COLUMN_NAME2]
 [SHCEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME3].[COLUMN_NAME1]
 [SHCEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME4].[COLUMN_NAME1]
 ...and so on
```

How can I remove the SCHEMA_NAME and the TABLE_NAME from the second column, so I only get the column_name?(since that info is already on the TableName.

Here is the code I came up with so far that gives you the output I mentioned.

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr =''

    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))--,TableName varchar(200))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('' + @SearchStr + '','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE         

                TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SAMPLE SCHEMA HERE'
                AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                            ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                    AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + '=' + @SearchStr2 +
                    ' OR' + @ColumnName + ' IS NULL '
                )
            END
        END   
    END

        SELECT  DISTINCT left(columnName, charindex('.', ColumnName, charindex('.',ColumnName )+1)-1) as tableName,ColumnName FROM #Results Order by tableName;


                DROP TABLE #Results
```

NOTE: If you want to run the code make sure you insert a schema in the line that says "SAMPLE SCHEMA HERE" or remove that line to search across an entire database

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This looks a lot like sql server.

Comment: I'd use [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) for SQL Server. @SeanLange judging from the link they posted I'd think you are correct and i removed the mysql tag.

Comment: It is SQL server, my bad. New to the site, I think I clicked on the suggested tag on accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PARSENAME`, you can update your final SELECT with the below snippet.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    left(columnName, charindex('.', ColumnName, charindex('.',ColumnName )+1)-1) as tableName,
    parsename(ColumnName,1) as ColumnName
    --quotename(parsename(ColumnName,1)) as ColumnName --if you want the brackets still 
FROM #Results 
Order by tableName;
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
declare @column varchar(256) = '[schema].[table].[column]'

select parsename(@column,1)
select quotename(parsename(@column,1)) --if you want the brackets still
```